# How could I control (decrease) the number 1 in my grid matrix?

Tags: python, list

I'm generating a `random matrix` with **1's** and **0's** and I created a matrix called grid with the same size. **I need to control the number of 1's by decreasing and increasing the number of 1's and put them in my grid matrix**. For example, if the matrix **x** has 60 numbers of ones, I need to decrease these 60 for example to 30 and put them in the grid matrix. The python code below shows the procedure. How could I fix it, please?

This is below my try. Could anyone help me to fix it, please?

```
import random
import numpy as np

x = [[random.randint(0,1) for i in range(10)]for j in range(10)]
grid = np.array([[0 for i in range(len(x[0]))]for j in range(len(x))])

for i in range(len(grid)):
    for j in range(len(grid[0])):
        if x[i][j] <= 0.9:
            grid[i][j] = 0
        else:
            grid[i][j] = 1
print(x)
print(grid)
```

Example of output:

```
x=
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

After decreasing the number of 1's grid will become as below:

```
grid =
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Can you please add your input and expected output?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas I edited my dear.

Comment: How do you decide how many 1's to remove?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas by using a condition *if x[i][j] <= 0.9:*

Comment: This condition does not do anything. It keeps the 0's as 0 and 1's as 1. My question was how do you decide there needs to be only 1 in the first row

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas Oh sorry I need to to create a grid. The ones will be the obstacles and zero the non-obsctales.

Comment: How do you decide which position to be an obstacle?